# Lint error when calling .then() inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, eslint

Here is the code:

```
buildImgSuccess(json) {
    if (typeof json !== "undefined") {
      if (json.filesUploaded.length) {
        //-- Update Saving Status --//
        this.setState({
          saving: true
        });
        //-- Set Vars --//
        let item = 0;
        let sortOrder = 0;
        let imgCount = this.state.images.length;
        if (!imgCount) {
          imgCount = 0;
        }
        while (item < json.filesUploaded.length) {
          //-- Determine if PDF Document was Uploaded --//
          if (json.filesUploaded[item].mimetype === "application/pdf") {
            //-- Handle Document Upload --//
            //-- Get Number of pages --//
            let theKey = json.filesUploaded[item].key;
            let theHandle = json.filesUploaded[item].handle;
            axios.get(`/getPhotos`, {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
              },
              transformRequest: (data, headers) => { delete headers.common.Authorization; }
            }).then(jsonResult => {
              let pageCount = 1;
```

Our lint compiler is producing this error

```
Don't make functions within a loop
```

Anytime there is a `.then()` or `.catch()` inside a loop.

Does anyone understand what the problem is with this code structure and any possible solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Which linter are you using? Doesn't it come with a documentation?

Comment: It's not about the `then` call, it's about the function expression you are passing to it. But yeah, you probably shouldn't do asynchronous things inside a `while` loop anyway.

Comment: As Bergi said, it's not about the `while` but the `then`.  You could always define your function _outside_ the loop, and just pass it by name into the `.then`.  However, as Bergi stated, you should probably _carefully_ evaluate whether you really want to be doing async processes in a while loop.

Comment: Okay, this is great information. thanks!

Comment: @BenAhlander Again, which linter are you using? EsLint?

Comment: @Bergi, yes we are using EsLint

Comment: @BenAhlander would appreciate an up vote as well :-) (gave you one as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the function outside of the `while` loop.

Creating inside recreates the function every loop which is non performant.

See below.

**Simplified Example - Wrong**

```
const i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
 const print = (i) => console.log(i++); //Created 10 times (0,1,...,8,9)
 print(i);
};
```

**Simplified Example - Correct**

```
const i = 0;
const print = (i) => console.log(i++); //Created once
while (i < 10) {
 print(i);
};
```

**With your code**

```
        const handleJsonResult = (jsonResult) => {
              let pageCount = 1;
              //...
        }
        while (item < json.filesUploaded.length) {
          //-- Determine if PDF Document was Uploaded --//
          if (json.filesUploaded[item].mimetype === "application/pdf") {
            //-- Handle Document Upload --//
            //-- Get Number of pages --//
            let theKey = json.filesUploaded[item].key;
            let theHandle = json.filesUploaded[item].handle;
            axios.get(`/getPhotos`, {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
              },
              transformRequest: (data, headers) => { delete headers.common.Authorization; }
            }).then(handleJsonResult);
            //...
       }
```